# unusual Listview error

Tags: android, listview, video, orientation

I made a small android application that maintains a list of video files on the sd-card and plays it. I am using a listview with text and two images in each row. The problem I just noticed is quite usual. In horizontal mode, only those list items that fit into the screen area appears as normal while those items who require scrolling to get appeared, are either in wrong order or they are just repetition of the items in the top of the list. Moreover, by scrolling up and down, sometimes the order of items changes.. I am using two xml files. First for list view and second for the contents of the listview. here is the code for both xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@drawable/bwgradient"
    android:dividerHeight="1.5px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="50dip"
  android:layout_height="50dip" 
  android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
  android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
  android:src="@drawable/cover" 
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:state_focused="false"
  android:listSelector="#00000000"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" 
  android:textSize="14dip" 
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>
  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/play"
  android:layout_width="30dip"
  android:layout_height="30dip" 
  android:src="@drawable/play" 
  android:onClick="imageClick"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Any possible suggestion ??

Comment: That sounds like an adapter problem with views getting recycle and not correctly updated. What does your adapter's getView method look like ?

Comment: I think it is somewhat related with Layout.. Because everything is absolutely fine when the orientation is vertical. I play videos and return back to my list which remains fine but Only when the orientation changes to horizontal, all problem occurs (list order is changed).. Any ideas??

Comment: In that case, could you post some of your layout's code to see what could be wrong with it ?

Comment: I have two main layout files. One for the listview and the other one for drawing two images and one textview in each row. here is the code ..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/bwgradient"
        android:dividerHeight="1.5px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
   </LinearLayout>

Comment: The above code was for main.xml. Here is the code of second xml file that consists of two images and one textview..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="50dip"
   android:layout_height="50dip" 
   android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
   android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
   android:src="@drawable/cover" 
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

Comment: <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text"
     android:state_focused="false"
     android:listSelector="#00000000"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1" 
   android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" 
   android:textSize="14dip" 
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>

Comment: <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/play"
   android:layout_width="30dip"
   android:layout_height="30dip" 
   android:src="@drawable/play" 
   android:onClick="imageClick"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

when  orientation changes from horizontal to portrait and vice verse,the activity will recreate itself(the Activity object destroyed and new Activity object will create).See docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges for more information